# Increase the PubSub acknowledgement time more than 600 sec or to set fire and forgot in pub-sub for long running cloud run jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have GCP cloud run with 60min execution timeout but I'm using PubSub to trigger it which has 10 min acknowledgment time. So pub-sub is retrying to send messages.

Is there a way to set trigger and forget in pub-sub? or to increase the pub-sub acknowledgment timeout to 60 min?

I found Cloud Task and Workflows but it has 30 min ack time but I'm looking for 60 min.

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998539/long-running-cloud-run-process-and-pubsub-message-retry ?

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix Thank you.
I have implemented an intermediate cloud function which calls cloud run. Everything is working fine but in between the execution of cloud run, the master is shutting down. 

Even after the master shutdown, the cloud is still running, but does this impact cloud run performance?