# How to trigger a long-running cloud run process without delay?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-tasks

tl;dr:

What is the best way to trigger long-running tasks (up to half an hour) on Cloud Run without a delay?
If this is not currently reliable are there any other serverless tools on GCP that can be used to run long-running tasks?

Details:

We have a following set up:

- Containerized backend app deployed in Cloud Run.
- The app contains of two parts called `App scheduler` and  `Worker`
- `App scheduler` is triggered by `Google Cloud Scheduler` every 5 minutes
- When run `App scheduler` identifies how many `Workers` to be run and triggers those
  `Workers`.
- Sometimes no worker needs to be run, other times it's hundreds of `Workers`. It takes between 1 and 30 minutes for a `Worker` to complete their job.

Now, we tried following ways to trigger workers (as recommended in Cloud Run docs https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service ):
Google Cloud Tasks
Pubsub

These methods result in a very long delay between `App Scheduler` pushing a Cloud Task or PubSub message and `Worker` starting running. These delays can be up to 30 minutes.

After doing my research I figured out that this is to do with the `Worker` running for a long time and the Cloud Run service not responding with 200 until `Worker` is done. These delays Cloud Tasks and Pubsub invocations of the workers.

I'm able to change this behaviour by running some ’fake workers’ that run very quickly, i.e. when for every real worker i push 20 fake/quick workers everything works as expected.

Another solution I found was to trigger `Worker` directly from `App Scheduler` as described in cloud run docs above for synchronous triggers specifying request timeout. That way I'm able to trigger multiple workers asynchronously.

I also tried to fix this by increasing number of CPUs and making at least 1 Cloud Run instance always available with no luck.

These work-arounds do not look reliable to me and therefore I'm searching for a better solution.

Another issue connected to this one is that sometimes when Google Cloud Scheduler triggers `App scheduler` its not being triggered with following error in Google Cloud Scheduler:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName":"projects/[OMITTED PROJECT]/locations/europe-west1/jobs/[OMITTED SERVICE NAME]", "status":"UNKNOWN", "targetType":"HTTP", "url":"https://[OMITTED SERVICE URL]"}
```

This usually coincides with long-running `Worker` running.

I wondering what are the best ways to run long-running Cloud Run services reliably.

Comment: How do you need to dispatch the worker? DO you need 1 worker per Cloud Run instance (to reserve it the full resources)? Or can you run several worker on the same instance? Do you need retries on worker failure, or you don't care about retries feature? Is it urgent?

Comment: One instance can run many workers. Don't need retries.
sorry what do you mean 'urgent'?

Comment: My containerised app is running fast api and so `App Scheduler` and `Worker` are triggered via http request.

Comment: Have you gone through the [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998539/long-running-cloud-run-process-and-pubsub-message-retry)?. Seems the answer posted by “Kamal Aboul-Hosn” may help you.